# MySQL, getting rows from table with latest date from 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql db where I import data every morning from an oracle db. The table is about 30million records. This takes about 5-6 hours.
At night then I duplicate the table so I can access it from a website that shows a grid with the table content.

the table looks like this

```
id     userID     fieldID    date1    date2
1         1           1       2014     2014
2         1           1       2014     2016
3         1           1       2013     2017
4         1           2       2014     2016
5         2           3       2014     2016
```

Basically on the website the user inputs userID and I have to show the records of each fieldID that have the latest date1, and then the latest date2
so the output for userID=1 should be:

```
id     userID     fieldID    date1    date2
2         1           1       2014     2016
4         1           2       2014     2016
```

The query I'm using so far is this:

```
SELECT id,UserID,fieldID,date1,date2 FROM mytable WHERE id = 
( SELECT id from mytable AS lookup 
  WHERE lookup.fieldID = mytable.fieldID
  ORDER BY date1 DESC, date2 DESC
  LIMIT 1 ) AND UserID=1
```

This works but it takes too long to query the server and load the page, while if I select everything for a specific userID it takes just a second to fetch around 2000 rows

I was wondering if you could suggest a better query or maybe a workaround where instead of duplicating the table, I create the new one with just the records I need (the website isn't used at night).

thanks

Comment: You should try to add and index on date1 and date2, and USERID

Comment: I think the SQL has some problems, though. Why isn't the UserID used in the internal query? That seems suspect. Check it. And then be sure you have an index on UserID, fieldID, date1, date2

Comment: This is a really strange request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
id,
UserID,
fieldID,
(SELECT MAX(date1) FROM mytable WHERE fieldID=mt.fieldID) As DateOne,
(SELECT MAX(date2) FROM mytable WHERE fieldID=mt.fieldID) As DateTwo,  
FROM mytable mt 
WHERE UserID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT  id, mytable.UserID, mytable.fieldID, A.date1, B.date2
FROM    mytable AS outer,
(
    SELECT      MAX(date1) AS date1
    FROM        mytable AS innerone
    WHERE       innerone.id=outer.id
    WHERE       innerone.UserID=outer.UserID
    AND         innerone.fieldID=outer.fieldID
    GROUP BY    innerone.id,
                innerone.UserID,
                innerone.fieldID
)       AS A,
(
    SELECT      MAX(date2) AS date2
    FROM        mytable AS innertwo
    WHERE       innertwo.id=outer.id
    WHERE       innertwo.UserID=outer.UserID
    AND         innertwo.fieldID=outer.fieldID
    GROUP BY    innertwo.id,
                innertwo.UserID,
                innertwo.fieldID
)       AS B
WHERE UserID=1
```